# WPF TopMost control

Tags: wpf

I have the following UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">
    <Canvas Background="Transparent">
        <Line x:Name="line"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Panel.ZIndex="99999999" />
        <Polygon Name="arrow" "/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

a) Is the `Panel.ZIndex="99999999"` a correct way to set this control as the TopMost in that control?

b) Will it change if I switch the visibility (Visible=>Invisible=>Visible) ?

Comment: If you're looking for a way to get the textblock drawn below the arrow but still get all user input, you can try using IsHitTestVisible flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an other option is just to change the order of elements in the node

```
<line/>

<arrow/>
<textBlock/>
```

Answer (score 3):

a) That is quite unclean, i'd suggest you add the system namespace

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And set it like this:

```
Panel.ZIndex="{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}"
```

b) That should have no effect.

Comment: It makes whatever item you add to the canvas the topmost, you have to keep in mind that the `Children` collection has an order of its own, it's not just a set. If you want to ensure that the order is independent from that you need to bind all the Z-Indices to some controller-class which manages this for you.

Answer (score 2):

a) Yes, though setting it to `1` would usually be sufficient.

b) No.